# Fuzzy Matching a paragraph within a large text

Tags: information-retrieval, fuzzy-search, plagiarism-detection

I need to do a pretty complex matching of phrases.
I have large bodies of text in files which exceed 1000 words each.

The phrases I am searching for (searchphrase) are like this:

> Investment does not mean:
>   i.  Claims to money that arise solely from:
>   1.  Commercial contracts for the sale of goods or 
>   services by a national or an enterprise of a party 
>   to an enterprise in the territory of the other party, 
>   or
>   2.  The extension of credit in connection with a 
>   commercial transaction, such as trade financing 
>   other than loans or claims to money previously
>   covered.

I want to know if the phrase occurs in each of the files I have. However, the files will not have content that are exact replicas of the phrase. Instead the file (textfile) will be a large document with a paragraph like:

> But investment does not mean claims to money derived solely from
>   commercial transactions designed exclusively for the sale of goods or
>   services by a national or legal person in the territory of one
>   Contracting Party to a national or legal person in the territory of the
>   other Contracting Party, credits to finance commercial transactions such
>   as trade financing, and other credits with a duration of less than three
>   years, as well as credits granted to the State or to a State enterprise.

As you can see, searchphrase is pretty similar in actual meaning to this paragraph from textfile. There is also considerable overlap in the keywords. Hence, I should get a match.

What sort of algorithm should I try and use to code this? Are pre-coded modules available anywhere that do this job?

Comment: Are you still interested in an answer to that? The solution is to use simhash. I can provide Python code.

Comment: You can use simhash algorithm, it works very well to find near duplicates.

Comment: @amirouche Could you share the code?

Comment: Any progress on this? :)